# Calling stored procedure from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am using codeigniter that has mysqli as db driver, am trying to call a simple stored procedure from my model but get an error. What am i doing wrong

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pc()' at line 1

pc()

Filename: C:\hosted\saner.gy\ipa\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

When i run the query call Stored Procedure it runs well but from codeigniter it throws the above error

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pc`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tbl_flo
  WHERE name = 'sam';
END
```

**Controller**

```
public function sp()
{
$this->User_model->pc();
}
```

**Model**

```
public function pc()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("pc()");

            return $query->result();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Stored procedures are invoked using the `CALL procedure_name(optional_params)` query.

You need to edit the query used in your model like this:

```
public function pc()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("CALL pc()");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Codeigniter not allows to call stored procedures in this way.

Comment: @semira, I don't see why it shouldn't, this is a regular query like any other. Anyways, this is a very old response, maybe things have changed?

Comment: Codeigniter not allows to pass parameters to stores procedures. It is a common problem in Codeigniter. Still it is not changed. Even if is a query like any other, Codeigniter always returns an error when it is a stored procedure with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This block of code work for me at model

```
function get_sunmeter_for_initiator($data){
        try {
            $this->db->reconnect();
            $sql = "CALL `get_sunmeter_for_initiator`(?, ?, ?)";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql,$data); // $data included 3 param and binding & query to db
            $this->db->close();

            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following way to call procedure.

```
$this->db->call_function('pc');
```

Or you can also use this

```
$this->db->query("call pc()");
```

Comment: Codeigniter not allows to call stored procedures in this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->query("CALL getWalletStatement($currency, '$date', '$date1', $type, 10000)")->getResult();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: This adds nothing new compared to the answers posted in 2015, and on top of that it introduces SQL injection.