# To call MySQL procedure in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[execution of stored procedure in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c0na.jpg)
i have two stored procedure first is without parameter and second is with two parameter. both are working fine in mysql as shown in image

i used the follwoing line to fetch the data in codeignitor but does not work

$sn=$this->session->userdata('running_session_id');
  $sid=$row['student_id'];

$studnet_name = $this->db->query("call fetch_student()");
  $row1 = $studnet_name->row_array();

$studnet_fee = $this->db->query("call fetch_student_fee_structure($sn,$sid)");
  $row2 = $studnet_fee->row_array();

because these procedure have very complex query so i need to fetch data in codeignitor

Comment: give us more detailed explanation of your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling stored procedure from codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067241/calling-stored-procedure-from-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

In your model use this code hope it will help you

```
public function getdata //you can change according to your requirements  
{
    return $this->db->get("table-name")->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i googled a lot and finally found solution of the above problem by adding the following code after calling the stored procedure in codeignitor.

mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );